# Vagrant scripts language

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to run a existing Vagrant scripts and notice the below lines.

In what language the Vagrant scripts are written, Is there a specific official documentation about these scripts?

```
machines = {
  "dev" => { :ip => "192.168.22.181", :mem => 2048 },
  "prod" => { :ip => "192.168.33.182", :mem => 2048 },
  "ops" => { :ip => "192.168.33.183", :mem => 2048 },
}
```

Comment: Official documentation: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/version.html (see nav on left for other subtopics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant is written in [Ruby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_(programming_language)) and so are its files like `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: Just to "complete" the answer to the OP - yes there is documentation: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/version.html  (see the nav on the left hand side for further topics)